# Error on loop cell to convert txt to date and put in array, after paste in range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I work with many records, and usually I use array to speed the code.
I have 2 columns (1= ID,2 = date YYYYMMDD FORMAT).

This is my code:

```
Sub ConvDateb(c As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrw As Long, i As Long
Dim avvio As Date, arresto As Date, tempo As Date
Dim ArrVal As Variant
avvio = Now
lrw = ActiveSheet().Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
ReDim ArrVal(2 To lrw, 1 To 2)
For i = 2 To lrw
    If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
        ArrVal(i, 1) = Cells(i, c - 1)
        ArrVal(i, 2) = Cells(i, c)
    Else
        Select Case Len(Cells(i, c))
            Case 8
                ArrVal(i, 1) = Cells(i, c - 1)
                ArrVal(i, 2) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case 6
                ArrVal(i, 1) = Cells(i, c - 1)
                ArrVal(i, 2) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case Else
                GoTo NextX
            End Select
    End If
NextX:
    Next i
Range(Cells(2, c - 1), Cells(lrw, c)) = ArrVal
Columns(c).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
Columns(c).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
arresto = Now
tempo = arresto - avvio
Debug.Print tempo

End Sub
```

this code run right (56K record) in 00:00:01.
so, I want remore the column 1 (ID) and I think"easy" then I change the code like:

```
Sub ConvDate(c As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrw As Long, i As Long
Dim avvio As Date, arresto As Date, tempo As Date
Dim ArrVal As Variant
avvio = Now
lrw = ActiveSheet().Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
ReDim ArrVal(2 To lrw)
For i = 2 To lrw
    If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
        ArrVal(i) = Cells(i, c)
    Else
        Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) 'to check is date like YYYYMMDD
            Case 8
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case 6
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case Else
                GoTo NextX
            End Select
    End If
NextX:
    Next i
Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)) = ArrVal
Columns(c).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
Columns(c).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
arresto = Now
tempo = arresto - avvio
Debug.Print tempo

End Sub
```

The code runs in the same time, but the result is:
For each 56K record, the value is the the date on the first cell (A1).
Why ?

Comment: off-topic from question, but this statement `GoTo NextX` is not necessary. the `Case` structure will ignore anything not 8 or 6 and just move on.

Comment: Scott Holtzman , right, It is a remnant of another code. thank.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your line:

```
Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)) = ArrVal
```

With:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrVal)
```

Comment: Shai Rado, work, I also did a test with numbers expression, and it works. Then we can assume that if the array is mono dimensional, must use Transpose(array), otherwise if the array dimensions are > 1, Transpose is not to be used ??

Comment: Shai Rado, with your solutioon I've two problems, the date is not correctly setting "dd/mm/yyyy", I resolve with CDbl(date), and second much more important is the limit to 65536 record!!!