# Paste one array (single dimension) with >100K item into a excel range

Tags: vba, excel

I posted the same question on StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077581/error-on-loop-cell-to-convert-txt-to-date-and-put-in-array-after-paste-in-range)
but I think here is the correct place to ask (if is not right, admin please to remove it).Every day I need to format date imported from AS400 (data, time,..).
Usualy (for some thousands of record) I use this code.

```
Public Sub Cfn_FormatDate(control As IRibbonControl)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim UR As Long, X As Long
    Dim MyCol As Integer
    MyCol = ActiveCell.Column
    UR = Cells(Rows.Count, MyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 2 To UR
        If Not IsDate(Cells(X, MyCol)) Then
            Select Case Len(Cells(X, MyCol))
            Case 8
                Cells(X, MyCol) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(X, MyCol), 4), Mid(Cells(X, MyCol), 5, 2), Right(Cells(X, MyCol), 2))
            Case 6
                Cells(X, MyCol) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(X, MyCol), 2), Mid(Cells(X, MyCol), 3, 2), Right(Cells(X, MyCol), 2))
            End Select
        End If
    Next X
Columns(MyCol).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
Columns(MyCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

but if the records are  are many more, the code posted code is not performing.
(ex 70K records were formatted / pasted in 18 seconds)
so I thought to using variables in an array and I wrote this code:

```
Sub ConvDate(c As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrw As Long, i As Long
Dim ArrVal As Variant
lrw = ActiveSheet().Range(Cells(1, c)).End(xlDown).Row
ReDim ArrVal(2 To lrw)
For i = 2 To lrw
    If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
        ArrVal(i) = Cells(i, c)
    Else
        Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) ' to check YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD
            Case 8
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case 6
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
        End Select
    End If
NextX:
    Next i
Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)) = ArrVal
Columns(c).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
Columns(c).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It not work, all the cells (in  the range) have the same result (Cells(2, c)).
a guy suggested me to change the code like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrVal)
```

this change is limiting , over 65536 records I get an error (runtime 13, type mismatch)

Comment: Your error is probably because `c` is an `Integer`, which has a size limit of 65,535. Make it a `Long` instead.

Comment: Zak ?!?!?!?  "c" is the column number, and it is fix.

Comment: My bad. an error on 65536 is \*almost\* always because you declared an `Int` somewhere that got overflown. I scanned the code, saw an `Int`, and assumed it was probably that.

Comment: Why don't you put the range into an array first before working with it? So use two arrays. You'll have to break it up first because of the 32 bit limitation Gareth mentioned. Do the first 30,000 and then the rest of it. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to summarise all the answers and comments:

1. As you have indicated in your question and as user85489 alludes, reading the values into an array, manipulating that same array, and writing it back to the sheet is vastly quicker than lopping cell by cell.
2. If you have an array whose 'row' dimension is not going to change. Then it might be fair to say that you're better off declaring a 2 dimensional array of size (1 to rows, 1 to columns). This way you can avoid having to transpose a 1 dimensional array at all.
3. Because as Gareth points out, `Transpose()` is limited to 65536 elements in a dimension.

Putting it all together, then, skeleton code for your post could be this:

```
Sub ConvertDates(colIndex As Long)
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim fullRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dd As Integer
    Dim mm As Integer
    Dim yy As Integer
    Dim dat As Date

    'Define the range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set firstCell = .Cells(2, colIndex)
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)
        Set fullRange = .Range(firstCell, lastCell)
    End With

    'Read the values into an array
    v = fullRange.Value

    'Convert the text values to dates
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If Not IsDate(v(i, 1)) Then
            If Len(v(i, 1)) = 6 Then v(i, 1) = "20" & v(i, 1)
            yy = CInt(Left(v(i, 1), 4))
            mm = CInt(Mid(v(i, 1), 5, 2))
            dd = CInt(Right(v(i, 1), 2))
            dat = DateSerial(yy, mm, dd)
            v(i, 1) = dat
        End If
    Next

    'Write the revised array and format range
    With fullRange
        .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
        .Value = v
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You have enclosed all in one post, thank you. With your code I learned a new way to manipolate large data sets, I love it 390K records are formatted on 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You have come across the [32 bit limitation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/548a528c-5f5f-49ac-a225-8cfb1bf9859c/problem-with-worksheetfunctiontranspose?forum=excel) of the function Transpose which truncates your array to 65536.

Answer (score -2):

You can use loop statement to populate the cells, else if you want to do it directly then define your array ArrVal like:

Redim ArrVal(1,Lrw) as variant

Flood the array with values and then, Offload it like

Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lrw, c)) = ArrVal

Hopefully you get rid of the same value errors.